# interface conversion: error is *errors.errorString, not validator.ValidationErrors

Tags: validation, go, go-gin

[image]

```
type BookInput struct {
  Title string `json:"title" binding:"required"`
  Price json.Number `json:"price" binding:"required,number"`
}

func PostBookHandler(ctx *gin.Context) {
  var bookInput book.BookInput

  err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&bookInput)

  if err != nil {
    errorMessages := []string{}

    for _, e := range err.(validator.ValidationErrors) {
        errorMessage := fmt.Sprintf("Error on filed %s, condition: %s", e.Field(), e.ActualTag())
        errorMessages = append(errorMessages, errorMessage)
    }

    ctx.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H {
        "errors": errorMessages, 
    })
    return
  }

  ctx.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H {
    "title": bookInput.Title,
    "price": bookInput.Price,
  })
}
```

I tried to validate the price input, but the results I got were unexpected. The code I wrote is like the one above, can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

The error returned in this case might *not* be a `validator.ValidationErrors`, it could be something else. For example if the body is invalid JSON, then the validation step isn’t reached at all.

In your code you are performing an unchecked assertion `range err.(validator.ValidationErrors)` which could panic.

This is how you could conditionally handle the error:

```
err := ctx.ShouldBindJSON(&bookInput)
if err != nil {
    var ve validator.ValidationErrors
    if errors.As(err, &ve) {
       // handle validator error
    }
    // handle non-validator error
    return
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can help:

```
type BookInput struct {
    Title string `json:"title" binding:"required"`
    
    Price interface{} `json:"price" binding:"required,number"`
}

func postBooksHandler(c *gin.Context) {
    var bookInput BookInput

    err := c.ShouldBindJSON(&bookInput)
    if err != nil {

        errorMessages := []string{}
        for _, e := range err.(validator.ValidationErrors) {
            errorMessage := fmt.Sprintf("Error on field %s, conditon: %s", e.Field(), e.ActualTag())
            errorMessages = append(errorMessages, errorMessage)

        }
        c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
            "error": errorMessages,
        })
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{
        "title": bookInput.Title,
        "price": bookInput.Price,
    })

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to create two conditions on error, because `validator.ValidationErrors` doesn't cover everything.

This my code:

```
if err != nil {
    var ve validator.ValidationErrors
    if errors.As(err, &ve) {
        for _, e := range err.(validator.ValidationErrors) {
            c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
                "error":   true,
                "message": "" + e.Field() + " kosong",
            })
            return
        }
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{
        "error":   true,
        "message": err.Error(),
    })
}
```